# Erro de sintaxe em query com filtro por código RFID

Tags: java, sql

Está dando erro de Syntax SQL na parte `from estoque where cod_rfid = 102`.
Obs.: 102 é o valor que está na tag RFID.

```
    String dadoRFID = new String(readBuffer);
    String Del_inc = dadoRFID.substring(0,1); //Pega o primeiro caractere
    String Del_local = dadoRFID.substring(5,6); //Pega o primeiro caractere

    System.out.println(Del_inc); 
    System.out.println(Del_local); 

    if((Del_inc.equals("#")) && (Del_local.equals("&"))  ) { //Se caracteres OK.
        msg_rec_str = dadoRFID.substring(6, 12); //Pega os prox 6 caracteres após o "#"
        loc_est_str = dadoRFID.substring(1,5);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Não encontrou");
    }

    System.out.println("MSG"+ msg_rec_str);
    System.out.println("teste"+ loc_est_str);
    try {
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistemarfid?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "12345");
         Statement statement=con.createStatement();

         Resultset rs= (Resultset) statement.executeQuery("select from estoque where cod_rfid =" + msg_rec_str);
         ((ResultSet) rs).next();
         int codrfid = ((ResultSet) rs).getInt(3);

         Resultset rs2= (Resultset) statement.executeQuery("select from estoque where endereco_estoque =" + loc_est_str);
         ((ResultSet) rs2).next();
         int localrfid = ((ResultSet) rs2).getInt(4);

         Resultset rs3= (Resultset) statement.executeQuery("select from estoque where estatus =" + 0);
         ((ResultSet) rs3).next();
         int estatusrfid = ((ResultSet) rs3).getInt(5);

             String dado_bd = "0"+ codrfid; //Variavel com o 
             String loc = "0"+localrfid; //Var com o retorno do local do BD
             String status_bd = "0"+ estatusrfid;           

             if(loc.equals(loc_est_str)) {
               System.out.println("LOCAL CONFIRMADO");
        switch (status_bd) { //Faz buscar para trocar
        case "0":
            System.out.println("status = 1");
            String sql1 = "update estoque set estatus = 1";
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            //stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

            con.close();

            break;
        case "1":
            System.out.println("status = 2");
            String sql2 = "update estoque set estatus = 1";
            PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            stmt2.executeUpdate();
            //stmt.execute();
            stmt2.close();

            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("status = 1");

            String sql3 = "update estoque set estatus = 1";
            PreparedStatement stmt3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
            stmt3.executeUpdate();
            //stmt.execute();
            stmt3.close();

            break;
        default:System.out.println("Status nao confirmado");
            break;
        }

             }else {
               System.out.println("LOCAL ERRADO");
             }
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Douglas. Esse campo `cod_rfid` da tabela `estoque` é numérico ou texto? Qual é a mensagem de erro exata que aparece?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, não quer postar a sua solução como uma resposta? Se quiser, explica um pouco mais sobre a sua sugestão, para deixa-la mais completa.

Comment: o campo cod_rfid no BD está como varchar e no código Java está como String

Answer (score 1):

nas suas *querys* faltou informar o que deseja selecionar.

Exemplo: `SELECT nome_coluna FROM estoque WHERE ....`

Comment: Tentei fazer desta forma:  Resultset rs= (Resultset) statement.executeQuery("select cod_rfid from estoque where cod_rfid =" + msg_rec_str);               Porém deu o seguinte erro java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 1.

Comment: Esse erro é dado por conta que você está tentando acessar um índice que não existe.

Comment: E como faço para comparar uma variável Java com um dado que está no BD ?

Answer (score 1):

Nas queries faltou informar qual coluna você quer selecionar. E isso deve ser feito antes do "FROM". 
Para não dar o erro de "Column Index out" tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 "SELECT nome_tabela.nome_coluna FROM estoque WHERE cod_rfid ="
```

- Usar um ponto entre o nome da tabela e o nome da coluna para especificar com mais exatidão o que se quer consultar.
- Tem outras duas queries com o mesmo erro.

Comment: fiz dessa forma:    Resultset rs= (Resultset) statement.executeQuery("select from estoque.cod_rfid where cod_rfid =" + msg_rec_str); e mesmo assim não deu certo